Maya to Blender/ Max to Blender Pivots changing
I've been trying to import grouped objects from Maya into Blender, these objects need to be grouped and they will also have groups inside them such as door and then those objects under that group will have their own pivots. Obviously lots of jumble in there, but my issue stems from the fact that the pivot will just turn into the top most parents pivot, and then get baked down everywhere. With these objects inside being instanced, I'd love to maintain these pivots, and am looking for a way to do that. Does anyone know of a way, even through a plugin to keep these?
